# Whats the purpose of width in "viewport" meta?

Tags: css, html, mobile, meta

What is `width` for if the only value "doing anything" is `device-width`?

Even `device-width` seems to make the viewport 320p on every mobile (not tablet) device. This makes perfect sense and simplifies stuff for actually responsive content and such.

But when using fixed values, it wont use the fixed value as viewport size, it seems to use 320p instead.

Am I doing anything wrong all the time, was it back in the days that fixed values even worked or what is it for?

EDIT: Specifically, Cordova seems to do it's own thing with viewports, too.

Comment: Well, the actual device width won't change, of course. You have a piece of hardware with a fixed amount of pixels. Now according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html), the browser emulates a document of 980 pixels wide in the absence of any viewport meta, with the phone screen being a viewport on that document. 980 pixels is the default, but you can set that to any other width you want. They use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=590">` as an example.

Comment: Hope that clears things up a bit. The page has a lot of screenshots. I don't have an iPhone here, so I can't check.

Comment: Fun fact: the website you mentioned is unusable on mobile. So it's an apple-only thing? Because on chrome (android) a fixed width won't emulate any other width.

Comment: Oh. I presumed that since Safari was the first to implement this, other browsers that did would copy the behaviour of Safari as closely as possible. At least that's what [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) says... But q&d tests on both real hardware and emulators are inconclusive. Not to say contradictory. So, sorry.